# how does 'window.location.href' work?

Tags: javascript

there is some code in "new.html" like

```
$('#publish').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "/index";
    alert(window.location.href);
    return false;
})
```

when it works with chrome debug, it display:

```
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/new
Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/index
```

why it can redirect to index?
if i remove "return false", it doesn't work conversely...I don't understand it...please give me some pointers...thank you!

Comment: What kind of element is `#publish`?

Comment: #publish is a button, code like:
<button id="publish" class="btn btn-primary">publish</button>

Comment: Put the code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: When you return false in an `onclick` event, you intend to tell Javascript that you want to prevent the default behaviour from happening which means that your click event will be stopped. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does not have anything to do with `window.location.href` btw

Comment: let's me give you an example, lets say, when your alarm rings --like when you click the button. You are going to start your car and drive to the store. Then your friends come over suddenly -- like you return false there, you stop your engine and will not go to the store anymore, just like that, when you return false, your click event will not be processed anymore. So you either return true or remove the return completely

Comment: @Dummy, thanks for your patient~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is in a form, the default action of clicking on the button is to submit the form. When the form is submitted, any Javascript that was in progress is cancelled. This includes a pending redirect from assigning to `window.location`.

When you `return false` from the click handler, you prevent the default action. This allows the redirect to be followed.

Comment: you are right! i try it that move '#publish button' out the form and delete code 'return false', redirecting to index works also~~Thanks~~!